# Verify is Armstrong number with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to do a code to verify whether or not the entered number is an Armstrong number, but my code does not work for every number.

Could anyone tell me what am I missing? Are there any other ways to do this?

Thank you!

```js
let e, x, d = 0;
let b = prompt("Enter a number");
x=b;

while (x > 0) {
  e = x % 10;
  x = parseInt(x/10);
  d = d + (e*e*e);
}

if (b==d)
   alert("given number is an armstrong number");
else
   alert("given number is not an armstrong number");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Armstrong</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code does not initialize `z`. The loop never runs.

Comment: An Armstrong number being a number that is equal to the sum of the cubes of each digit? (http://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap04/arms.html) I don't think that's what your algorithm does.

Comment: @Filburt where is `z` initialized to 0? The initial declaration statement only initializes `d`.

Comment: Also, even if `z` were initialized, the loop doesn't change the value of `z` anyway.

Comment: @Filburt try it yourself. That declaration statement only initializes `d`. Each variable in a `var` declaration needs its own initialization expression in order to be initialized.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can try for This, May this help for you:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Armstrong</title>
        </head>
            <body>

            </body>
            </html>

    <script>
    var z,e,x,d=0;
    var b=prompt("Enter a number");
    x=parseInt(b);
    while(x>0)  //Here is the mistake
    {
    e=x%10;
    x=parseInt(x/10);
    d=d+(e*e*e);
    console.log("d: "+d+" e: "+e);

    }
    if(parseInt(b)==d){

    alert("given no is amstrong number");
    }
    else {

    alert("given no is not an amstrong number");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it

Comment: It's ok @SReddy

Comment: @SReddy The code above sort of works only when the entered number has 3 digits, otherwise the algorithm is wrong. Just try it with a longer Armstrong number like 1634.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you compute the result is wrong. According to Wikipedia, an Armstrong number, also called narcissistic number, has the following property:

> [An Armstrong number] is a number that is the sum of its own digits each raised to the power of the number of digits.

You can compute it like this:

```js
var number = prompt("Enter a number");
var numberOfDigits = number.length;
var sum = 0;

for (i = 0; i < numberOfDigits; i++) {
  sum += Math.pow(number.charAt(i), numberOfDigits);
}
 
if (sum == number) {
  alert("The entered number is an Armstrong number.");
  
} else {
  alert("The entered number is not an Armstrong number.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this method, very easy to understand.

```
const armstrongNumber = (num) => {

    const toArray = num.toString().split('').map(Number);

    const newNum = toArray.map(a => {return a**3}).reduce((a, b) => a + b);

    if(newNum == num){
        console.log('This is an armstrong number');
    }else{
        console.log('This is not an armstrong number');

    }
}
armstrongNumber(370);
//This is an armstrong number
```

Comment: This is a good and clean solution but only works with 3 digits, it fails to verify with 4 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to check Armstrong number without using Math Object.

```
function armstrongNum(number) {
    const   numberArr = String(number).split('');
    const power = numberArr.length;
    let TotalSum = numberArr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      return acc + (function(cur,power){
        let curNum = Number(cur);
        let product = 1;
        while(power > 0) {
          product *= curNum;
          power --;
        }
        return product;
      }(cur,power))
    }, 0)
    if (TotalSum === number) {
      return true
    }
    return false
}
armstrongNum(153);
```

Comment: It would improve your answer if you explained what the OP missed and explain what your code does differently.

Comment: @user2653663 Thanks for your suggestion :)  it is just a solution to the problem like any others. i have just used ES6 and useful Array method(reduce) which simplify the coding.

Answer (score 0):

## Here is an example of functional code for Armstrong Numbers.

```
    <script>
        function execute() {
            var num1 = document.getElementById("Number1").value;
            var num2 = document.getElementById("Number2").value;
            var num3 = document.getElementById("Number3").value;
            var concatNum = num1 + num2 + num3;

            var num1Sqrt = num1 * num1 * num1;
            var num2Sqrt = num2 * num2 * num2;
            var num3Sqrt = num3 * num3 * num3;

            if (num1Sqrt + num2Sqrt + num3Sqrt == concatNum) {
                Answer.value = "The three integers you entered are Armstrong numbers.";
            }
            if (num1Sqrt + num2Sqrt + num3Sqrt != concatNum) {
                Answer.value = "The three integers you entered are not Armstrong numbers.";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

You first set your variables to what is entered, you then concatenate the string with the three integers.

You then square the three integers and set each value to a variable. You then have a basic check for equality, if the three squared values add up to your concatenated string then you have an Armstrong number.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved mine:

```
function armstrong(num) {

  var digits = num.toString().split('')
  var realDigits = num
  var a = 0

  for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++){
    digits[i] = Math.pow(digits[i], digits.length)
    a += digits[i]
  }

  if (a == realDigits) {
    console.log("Number is armstrong")
  } else if (a != realDigits) {
    console.log("Number is not armstrong")
  }


}

armstrong(371)
//feel free to pass any value here
```

You can copy/paste and run this code at https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This works as well..

```js
function isArmstrong (n) {
    const res = parseInt(n, 10) === String(n)
        .split('')
        .reduce((sum, n) => parseInt(sum, 10) + n ** 3, 0);
    console.log(n, 'is', res, 'Armstrong number')
    return res
}

isArmstrong(153)
```

Comment: a better code description would benefit more users who would like to understand why this code works not like `This works as well..`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to solve it.

```
let c = 153
let sum = 0;

let d = c.toString().split('');

console.log(d)

for(let i = 0; i<d.length; i++) {
   sum = sum + Math.pow(d[i], 3)
}
if(sum == c) {
    console.log("armstrong")
}
else {
    console.log("not a armstrong")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Correct way to find Armstrong

```
var e, x, d = 0, size;
var b = prompt("Enter a number");
b=parseInt(b);
x=b;
size = x.toString().length;
while (x > 0) {
  e = x % 10;
  d = d + Math.pow(e,size);
  x = parseInt(x/10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//This is I solved without function
let num = prompt();
let num1 = num;
let sum = 0;
while(num > 0){
    rem = num % 10;
    sum = sum + Math.pow(rem, num1.length);
    num = parseInt (num /10); 
}
if (sum == num1) console.log("Armstrong");
else console.log("not Armstrong");
```

Answer (score 0):

number is an Armstrong number or not.

```js
 

let inputvalue=371
let spiltValue=inputvalue.toString().split('')
let output=0
spiltValue.map((item)=>output+=item**spiltValue.length)
alert(`${inputvalue} ${inputvalue==output? "is armstrong number" : "is not armstrong number"}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

> In order to get a Narcissistic/Armstrong number, you need to take the
> length of the number as `n` for taking the power for summing the
> value.

Here's another solution that works with an input `>= 3` digits
(With `Math.pow()` each character is added as a number to the power of the array size)

```
const isArmstrongNumber = (n) => {
  //converting to an array of digits and getting the array length
  const arr = [...`${n}`].map(Number);
  let power = arr.length;

  const newNum = arr
    .map((a) => {
      return Math.pow(parseInt(a), power);
    })
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b);

  return newNum == n;
};

console.log("Is it Armstrong? " + isArmstrongNumber(370));
console.log("Is it Armstrong? " + isArmstrongNumber(123));
console.log("Is it Armstrong? " + isArmstrongNumber(1634));
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this help you output without using any function.

```js
let armstrongNumber = '153';
armstrongNumber = isNaN(armstrongNumber) ? armstrongNumber : armstrongNumber.toString();
let sumationValue = 0;
let result = (function () {
  for (var digit of armstrongNumber) {
    sumationValue += parseInt(digit) ** armstrongNumber.length;
  }
  return sumationValue;
})();

if (result == armstrongNumber) {
  console.log(armstrongNumber + ' is an Armstrong Number');
} else {
  console.log(armstrongNumber + ' is not an Armstrong Number');
}
```